# Are there any benefits to completing all outstanding invites before starting the WSR?

Tags: grid-2

Once you have enough fans, you get an offer to create the World Series Racing league, you're warned before doing this that any outstanding invites from the existing racing leagues will be cancelled as a result (since those drivers will join you in the creation of the WSR).

[image]

Should I create the World Series Racing league immediately or are there benefits to completing all of my outstanding invites?

Will skipping the existing open invites result in me missing out on anything other than additional fans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the additional fans (and potentially the vehicle from the vehicle challenge if you chose to do the races instead of the challenge to get fans) there are no additional bonuses or achievements from completing all of other invitational races before setting up the World Series Racing league.